# Why am I getting this WebDriver exception in Chrome and not in Firefox

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is the error

```
WebDriverException: Message: "findElement execution failed;\\n Property \'Error\' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function"
```

I run:

```
LoginPage.authenticate(self, self.admin_user)
```

This works fine, logs me in OK, but as soon as I try to find an element on the next page using the chrome driver:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id('Menu_LogInOut')
```

I get the above error.  It doesn't error out in Firefox.

Has anyone else run into this?  What is going on?  How do I get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had inadvertently overwritten window.Error in our application.  Thank you webdriver for pointing this out.

The fix is to not do this, something like window.Error_These_arent_the_droids_youre_looking_for.

XD